# Cloudbees oracle external database through VPN

Tags: database, oracle, external, vpn, cloudbees

Currently we have tomcat 6 webapp and oracle database. Database is configured as follows in server.xml:

```
<Resource
name="jdbc/EbankWebConnection"
auth="Container"
type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
user="***" password="***" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.12.2:1521:prg11g"
validationQuery="select 1 from dual" />
```

Notice, we're using oracle connection pool.
Is it possible to host tomcat webapp in to the CloudBees and connect to oracle db through VPN on our servers. Regarding connection pool, DBCP is not the case. We need somehow to config container managed oracle connection pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudbees container won't provide as JNDI resource an Oracle specific datasource, that would require the container to be customized. You can use dedicated code to create such a pool as part of your application using oracle jdbc driver classes, this mostly depends on the flexibility your application / frameworks allow for setting the datasource.

There is plan to expose soon some more flexibility for container customization, so that you could setup a tomcat server to provide such a container-managed Oracle DataSource, stay tunned!

About connecting through VPN, this is not possible yet. You have to let the cloudbees RUN@Cloud instance access your DB via standard network connection. An option if you use RUN@Cloud "dedicated" servers is to filter incoming IPs to connect to your DB. Contact sales@cloudbees.com if you need detailed infos on dedicated servers pricing.

update: you should consider solutions like InterCloud for VPN